# I am not able to format the Date of "Wed Jun 06 00:00:00 GMT 1990" to "DD/MM/YYYY"

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am not able to format the Date of `"Wed Jun 06 00:00:00 GMT 1990"` to `"DD/MM/YYYY"`

i have written below code but it is giving error of method does not exist or incorrect signature

**`profile.Birthday__c`** is of Date type **`string`**

```
bufferdate=this.profile.Birthday__c.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Can anyone help me with this

Regards,
Keerthan Shetty

Comment: What is the profile here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options (assuming bufferdate is a string):

1) if you org locale is the desired output:

`bufferdate=this.profile.Birthday__c.format();`

2) if not

```
Date d = this.profile.Birthday__c;
bufferdate = pad(d.month())+'/'+pad(d.day())+'/'+d.year();

private static String pad(Integer i){
     String s = String.valueOf(i);
     if(s.lenght() < 2) s = '0'+s;

     return s;
}
```